# find sum of datatable column containing decimal value

Tags: c#

Hi I have a datatable with 2 column as a string type which contains number like 12.5 etc. I have to compute sum of column, but when I am going to change it as decimal 12.5 is gretting changed to 125.

Please help me, I am stuck at this point.

Comment: Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51895407/edit) and show us what C# code you are using.

Comment: Please share the code that you were using.

Comment: If you KNOW that the value is always converted like that, you could calculate the sum and then divide the answer by 10.   If you have 12.45 -> "1245" and "12.5" -> 125, then you have a problem.